# Change element class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm not certain why this won't work, maybe someone can help. I got this code:

```
<dd class="accordion-navigation">
  <a href="#panel3" class="switch"><i class="plus"></i> Title</a>
  <div id="panel3" class="content">
    ...
  </div>
</dd>
```

When I click on the `<a>` I'd like the class of the i-element switch from 'plus' to 'minus'. This is the code I have so far:

```
$('dd.accordion-navigation').on('click', 'a.switch' function(){
  $(this).find(i).removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
});
```

Unfurtunatly it does not work. I would be really happy, if I could get a hint.

Thanks in advance
Florian

Comment: You are not passing the `find` function a string... it's thinking `i` is a variable.

Comment: Typo: `find(i)` vs `find('i')`.

Comment: Also, you can use `.toggleClass('plus minus');` here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the selector from a variable to a selector.

```
$(this).find('i').removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
```

This would work.

In the code above, you were having `i` which in this context would have been a variable. But you don't have any variables, to get the data or value from. So, you need to be passing a String to detect the HTML element. `'i'` in this case would be valid. Otherwise you can create a seperate variable, with the value of string `i` element. Like this

```
var i = 'i';
```

...and then you can use it. Otherwise, you'll have to stick to the conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a variable `i = "i";`, that won't find anything.

```
$('dd.accordion-navigation').on('click', 'a.switch' function(){
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
});
```